# How to click on an hidden element of type href = "#" using selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on an element in dropdown, The element is hidden initially when clicking on it, the   list is displayed, I want click on one of the names in the list.
I tried using the select drop down.. find by visbile text method but getting an error which say the element is type of input and not dropdown.

I tried using xpath,Css selector, linkname and Partiallinktext but none worked.

HTML for the element which i need to click is as below:

```
<div class="dropdown" style="display: none;">
<div class="search">
<div class="tree" style="display: block;">
<ul class="open">
<li>
<a class="parent open" href="#"></a>
<a class="current" data-nodeid="7" data-name="Global" data-nodemetadata="Global,Global" data-fullname="Global" href="#">Global</a>
<ul class="open">
<li>
<li>
a data-nodeid="807" data-name="Akram" data-nodemetadata="Akram,akram" data-fullname="Akram" `href="#">Akram</a>`
</li>
<li>
```

I want to click  on 'Akram' element. Any help will be appreciated.

Is there a way of passing Variable name in Xpath String, like in the above case Instead of clicking on 'Akram' by I want to click on any other text, So Is it possible to add this text to variable and use the variable inside the xpath "//div[@class='dropdown']//a[text()='Akram']"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please add a snapshot of what your dropdown looks like ?

Comment: I cannot upload an image, Adding dropbox link, Pls download and see the img. https://www.dropbox.com/s/d8bl9smymeh3eao/test.png?dl=0

Comment: Please check the below answer by **@Oleksii**. I would suggest you to do the same.. Because for using the **Select class and its methods**, the dropdown need to be of [**select type**](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebDriver doesn't allow to click on hidden elements. Naїve approach is just to perform 2 clicks. First on the drop down and second on the option:
`click "//div[@class='dropdown']"` then it will show up, and you `click "//div[@class='dropdown']//a[text()='Akram']"`. Also there is a possibility that when performing second click, drop down option still could be hidden, in that case you need to wait for them to show up first.

Comment: Is there a way of passing Variable name in Xpath String, like in the above case Instead of clicking on 'Akram' I want to click on any other text, So Is it possible to add this text to variable and use the variable inside the xpath "//div[@class='dropdown']//a[text()='Akram']"

Comment: What language do you use? You need to look for strings concatenation in that language. Possibly you can do like this: String opt = "Akram"; String xpath = "//div[@class='dropdown']//a[text()='" + opt + "']";

Comment: I am using Java, Thanks for the help Oleksii Matiiasevych, The above solution worked.